# Flutter : Unable to load image asset

Tags: image, flutter, assets

This is the first time I have used flutter, followed all that is described in the documentation and adding an image to the widget. But I get this error, I can not understand what did wrong

> Am tried this way

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Image.asset("drawables/ic_launcher_transparent.png", width : 100, height: 100),
    );
  }
```

- File structure 
  |-- lib
  |--- drawable
  |----- ic_launcher_transparent.png

- pubspec.yaml
    uses-material-design: true 
      assets: 
        - drawables

> Am getting this error

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: drawables/ic_launcher_transparent.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:668:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:651:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "drawables/ic_launcher_transparent.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#59d28(), name: "drawables/ic_launcher_transparent.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: please change `drawables` to `drawables/` in `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is inside lib folder. So you need to link lib in url. Check below.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Image.asset("lib/drawables/ic_launcher_transparent.png", width : 100, height: 100),
  );
}
```

And Pubspec will be like below.

- pubspec.yaml
    uses-material-design: true
      assets:
        - lib/drawables/